# Timeout value is negative

Tags: java, mysql

Currently I am doing a project with a 2 other guys and we have a MySQL Thread which needs to sleep a period of time to keep the connection alive (Game server).

2 of us keep getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative

The third person of our project does not have this problem.

The error happens because of this line:

```
Thread.sleep(5000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time));
```

I'm using JDK 1.8.0_111 if its relevant.

Comment: what is the value of start_time?

Comment: Clearly `System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time > 5000` i.e. it's been more than 5 seconds since start. What did you expect? Have you considered `Math.max(0,...)`?

Comment: That means that more than 5K milliseconds already passed and `5000 -
 x (where x > 5000)` gives negative value, `Thread.sleep` doesn't accept negative values, so what is the question?

Comment: Yeah I would output the values into a log and let it run and see what cases are creating it. Mind you if `System.currentTimeMillis - start_time` > 5000 that would be a key indicator.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, 5000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [absolute value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_abs.htm). That way you'll never have a negative value.

```
Thread.sleep(Math.abs(5000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your calculation to generate time for sleep was negative hence it shows this error.

If you want to use this calculation then I would use `TimeUnit` which supports negative value.

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(5000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time));
```

If you want to sleep for a certain time I would recommend using Random to generate the sleep time

```
int delay = new Random().nextInt(maxMili - minMili) + minMili;
System.out.println(String.format("Sleeping for %d milliseconds", delay));
Thread.sleep(delay);
```

Here maxMili and minMili are the ranges